# IBAction as static void in theos

Tags: objective-c, ios10, jailbreak, theos, tweak

I have a static void that creates a button with an action and I want the action to be a static void too but when I try to make the package I get an error.

Code:

```
typedef enum {
  SBIconLocationHomeScreen = 0,
  SBIconLocationDock       = 1,
  SBIconLocationSwithcer   = 2
} SBIconLocation;

static UIButton *okbtn;

@interface SBApplicationIcon
- (void)launchFromLocation:(SBIconLocation)location context:(id)arg2;
@end

static void AddBtn()
{
  UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

  okbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [okbtn addTarget:window action:@selector(checkpw:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [okbtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [okbtn setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  okbtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 40);
  okbtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  [UIView transitionWithView:window duration:0.4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations: ^ {
      [window addSubview:okbtn];
  } completion:nil];
  [window addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                             constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-255-[okbtn(40)]"
                             options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                             metrics:nil
                             views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(okbtn)]];
  [window addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                             constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[okbtn(160)]"
                             options:0
                             metrics:nil
                             views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(okbtn)]];
  [window addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintWithItem:okbtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:window attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
}

static void checkpw()
{
  //Something
}

%hook SBApplicationIcon
- (void)launchFromLocation:(SBIconLocation)location context:(id)arg2
{
  AddBtn();
}
%end
```

Error:

```
Tweak.xm:43:13: error: unused function 'checkpw' [-Werror,-Wunused-function]
static void checkpw()
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please include both the error as well as the actual code in your question on-site, do not link to external sites for essential content.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with these two sections of code:

```
[okbtn addTarget:window action:@selector(checkpw:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// …

static void checkpw()
{
  //Something
}
```

You're using a plain-old C method as a Selector. Selectors only work with Objective-C methods; you'll need to create an Objective-C class and add the method to it:

```
[okbtn addTarget:[[PasswordChecker alloc] init] action:@selector(checkpw:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// …

@implementation PasswordChecker
- (void)checkpw:(NSString *)password {
    // Something
}
@end
```